# iTunes no longer prompting user to download pictures from iPhone

Tags: windows, itunes

A friend has an iPhone running iOS 7, and iTunes on her Windows 8 computer.

Since iPhone appears not to allow choosing a lower definition when taking pictures, her phone no longer had enough memory. She then spent a couple of hours deleting old pictures, but iPhone stills complains that there's not enough memory left, refuses to take more pictures, and tells her to upload the remaining pictures to the Cloud. 1GB worth of pictures would take too long and cost money too (in bandwidth use, storage, and time.)

Moving pictures to her Windows computer through USB would be much faster (and free, too), but at this point, when plugging the phone into the computer, iTunes no longer prompts her whether she wants to copy pictures from the phone to the computer.

I don't own any Apple product so am not used to iTunes: Does someone have an idea why it would stop prompting users when plugging the phone, how to re-enable this feature, and download pictures from her phone to make room?

Answer (score 0):

iTunes has never synced photos *from* the phone... only *to* it.

On Windows you need something like [Photo Gallery](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows-live/photo-gallery) [part of Win Essentials] to transfer the camera roll to the PC.

The lower definition option, btw, was an iOS 8 feature

Comment: Thanks but like I said, until a few weeks ago, when she plugged into the computer, iTunes would start and offer to sync both devices, ie. that includes new pictures she had in her phone that didn't exist on her computer. I'll check out Photo Gallery and other utilies.

Comment: Offering to sync is one thing, actually copying over the photos is another. It has never done that. On the Mac it would automatically launch iPhoto to do that task. PC has no default app to do that, you need to install one that will work. Photo Gallery is one that does, my partner used it until she got a Mac. [Alternative explanation is she had an app that would do it, but no longer does...]